# Apps crash too slow

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, crashes

Every time an app crashed on my Galaxy S my phone vibrates, 15-25 seconds later it vibrates a little longer, shows an error message and asks if I want to close the app or wait.
I don't know why this takes so long. I developed an app myself and noticed that the same app crashed instantly in the android simulator, while it would take a really long time to crash on my phone. (I don't think it is because the pc is faster, because the app itself runs slower on the pc just the crashes are faster)

That's really annoying somtimes because some of the apps I use crash regularly and I always have to wait this long. So I wondered if there is some way to change this or if this is the same on all Galaxy S/Android phones.

Comment: Do you have the GT-i9000?  Do you have any task killers, or anything related that might affect this?

Comment: yes i have the gt-i9000 and no i don't have any task killers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve the problem by updating to the newest firmware with Kies.
Now my build number is FROYO.XXJQ3 and everythings works as it should.

Comment: My Galaxy S still slows down over time, but I figured out that it helps to wipe the dalvik cache from recovery menu.
The next boot takes ca. 10 mins, but the phone works nice and fast again afterwards.